# Python dunder methods wrapped as property

Tags: python, python-descriptors, python-datamodel

I stumbled upon this code that I found weird as it seems to violate the fact that python builtins call dunder methods directly from the class of the object. Using `__call__` as an example, if we define class `A` as following:

```
class A:
    @property
    def __call__(self):
        def inner():
            return 'Called.'
        return inner

a = A()
a() # return 'Called.'

type(a).__call__(a) # return 'property' object is not callable.
```

However, this behaviour seems to contradict with what's said in Python's official documentation:

> `object.__call__(self[, args...])` Called when the instance is “called”
> as a function; if this method is defined, `x(arg1, arg2, ...)` roughly
> translates to `type(x).__call__(x, arg1, ...)`.

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it respects the way to retrieve a method from a given function - We can see that the `__get__`  method is called:

On the code bellow, I just replaced `property` with a simpler descriptor that will retrieve its "func" - and used it as the `__call__` method.

```
In [34]: class X:
    ...:     def __init__(self, func):
    ...:         self.func = func
    ...:     def __get__(self, instance, owner):
    ...:         print("descriptor getter called")
    ...:         return self.func
    ...: 

In [35]: class Y:
    ...:     __call__ = X(lambda: "Z")
    ...: 

In [36]: y = Y()

In [37]: y()
descriptor getter called
Out[37]: 'Z'
```

So, the "dunder" functionality just retrieved the method through its `__get__` as usual for all methods. What was skipped is the step that goes through `__getattribute__` - Python will go directly to the `__call__` slot in the `A` class, and not go through the normal lookup sequence, by calling `__getattribute__`, which starts at  the class (for a descriptor), then looks at the instance, than back to the class (for a regular attribute): it assumes that if there is something at the instance's class dunder slot it is a method, and uses its `__get__` method accordingly.

A function's `__get__` is used when retrieving it from an instance - as that is the mechanism that injects the instance as the `self` argument for the call.

And `__get__` is exactly the thing that `property` replaces to perform its "magic".

To demonstrate that `__getatribute__` is not called, in iPython, I had to encapsulate "y" inside a dummy function, otherwise iPython would trigger `__getattribute__` when trying to autocomplete stuff:

```
In [42]: class Y:
    ...:     __call__ = X(lambda: "Z")
    ...:     def __getattribute__(self, name):
    ...:         print("getattribute called")
    ...:         return super().__getattribute__(name)
    ...: 

In [43]: def w():
    ...:     y = Y()
    ...:     return y()
    ...: 

In [44]: w()
descriptor getter called
Out[44]: 'Z'
# in contrast with:

In [46]: Y().__call__()
getattribute called
descriptor getter called
Out[46]: 'Z'
```

Answer (score 4):

When the Python language internals look up magic methods to implement language features, they bypass `__getattribute__` and the instance dict. However, they do *not* bypass the descriptor protocol.

`a()` finds the `__call__` property you defined, finds that it's a descriptor, and calls `descriptor.__get__(a, A)`. This delegates to the getter you wrote, which returns an `inner` function. Then Python treats this `inner` function as the result of the `__call__` lookup, and calls it.

`type(a).__call__(a)` is a manual call to `__call__`, so it goes through the regular attribute lookup process. It finds the `__call__` property you defined, and finds that it's a descriptor, but since you're looking up the property on the class instead of the instance, it calls `descriptor.__get__(None, A)`. This returns the property object itself, instead of calling the property getter. Then you attempt to call the property as a function, and get a TypeError.

(The docs you're quoting say `x(arg1, arg2, ...)` *roughly* translates to `type(x).__call__(x, arg1, ...)`. It's not a completely exact equivalence, but if they put something in those docs that handles every weird special case, it would have taken way too much code and obscured the point.)